# Trilateration of a Received Signal

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, coordinate-systems, nonlinear-system, spherical-coordinates

I'm trying to determine if this is even possible.

I have 2 unknowns that I want to solve for. The strength of an RF pulse and it's location in xyz coordinates.

The only knowns are the four locations in 3 dimensional space of the antenna, and the received signal strength at each antenna.

I've tried working the math out through trilateration methods and the inverse square law for EMI, but I can't shake the feeling that I'm just not smart enough to solve it or that it's impossible simply because I need to know something about the signals source. My issue then, is that I cannot know anything about the source, besides the fact that it must be within a defined space.

Do I need to perform a controlled measurement to obtain a calibration value? If that's the case, I'm out of luck since I can't afford to drop thousands for  the necessary equipment just to do a measurement that may not even help to solve this problem.

Any experts on GPS, RF and trilateration algorithms out there who can offer some insight towards what I'm missing here?